# Parsing info from an HTM/XML site

Tags: r, xml2

I would like R to tell me if the "Emerging growth company" box is checked on the following website:

`https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/0001817786/000141057822000680/rchg-20211231x10k.htm`

How can I do it? Of course, my actual problem is more complex than this. But this the nut that I need to crack first.